# Why I don't have the permission to save the file into SD Card?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

I want to use the file explorer in Android system to show the file I saved before.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

So, I think saving the data into SD card is the only way to achieve this. I've found many materials, but I always get the error that I don't have the permission to save the data into SD card. The error message is as follow.

```
01-17 23:35:44.184 6337-6337/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/rtd: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
01-17 23:35:44.184 6337-6337/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
01-17 23:35:44.185 6337-6337/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
01-17 23:35:44.185 6337-6337/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
```

In fact I do add the permission lines in the AndroidManifest

```
</activity>

    </application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
```

So, can anyone help me figure out what I should do to fix this error?
Here is the code of my saving button

```
 class ButtonClickListener2 implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
      //      Intent intent = getIntent();
            Name = getIntent().getStringExtra("Name");
            Age = getIntent().getStringExtra("Age");
            Movie = getIntent().getStringExtra("Movie");
            File2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("File");
            TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            txt.setText(Name+" "+ Age+ " "+Movie+" "+ File2);
            String filename = File2.toString();
            String Age_Content = Age.toString();
            String Movie_Content = Movie.toString();
            String Name_Content = Name.toString();
            FileService service = new FileService(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())){
                    service.save(filename, Age_Content, Movie_Content,Name_Content);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.SDCard_available,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.SDCard_protected,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.success,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.fail,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }
    class FileService {
        private Context context;
        public FileService (Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }
        public void save(String filename, String Age_content, String Movie_content, String Name_content) throws Exception{
            //save the data into SD card
           /* FileOutputStream outputStream = context.openFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_APPEND);
            outputStream.write(Age_content.getBytes());
            outputStream.write(Movie_content.getBytes());
            outputStream.write(Name_content.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();*/
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),filename);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            outputStream.write(Age_content.getBytes());
            outputStream.write(Movie_content.getBytes());
            outputStream.write(Name_content.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Define this permission in your manifest file
`<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your suggestion. But it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Android M, try this:

```
private final String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        requestPermissions(permissions, 2909);
```

Also, override the `onRequestPermissionsResult` method as follows:

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Your activity must extend AppCompatActivity in order for this to work.
Android has introduced runtime permissions with version 6.0. You might want to look into it.

Comment: Your suggestion is quite cool for me!! But I don't know how to add that code? Can you tell more detail about how to do it?

Comment: Yeah sure. You just need to add the aforementioned code to your activity which needs the permissions. Add the code till requestPermissions() in your onCreate() method and override the method outside onCreate(), and you're done.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I tried your method already. The App always ask me if I allow this app to use the information from the cellphone. However, I'm still unable to save the data in SD card. I'm using the emulator Galaxy Nexus API23. Is there anything wrong with my emulator choice? The error message is like this. 1:30.373 17763-17763/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/zsy2053: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: Try adding the following lines to your manifest inside the <manifest> tag right above your other permissions:
<permission
        android:name="com.yourapp.permission.READ_GALLERY"
        android:description="@string/your_description"
        android:label="@string/your_label"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.STORAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />


<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="23" />

Comment: Use the above lines for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as well.

Comment: Yes, right now. I can save the data, and I can use the file explorer to see it. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
In your manifests file put the below code 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked the code in my AndroidManifest.xml, and I have everything you wrote. But the error still exist

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you used PERMISSIONS in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked the code in my AndroidManifest.xml, and I have everything you wrote. But the error still exist